# How to avoid combining multiple buffers into one UDP packet with function call WSAsend?

Tags: windows, sockets, winapi, network-programming, udp

I am writing WIN32 code to send data on UDP socket. To make better performance, WSASend() is called with multiple buffers. But the result is that all data in these buffers are combined into one UDP packet. I need separate UDP packet for data in each buffer. Is there anyway to do that? WIN32 doesn't support sendmmsg() in Linux which I believe can do what I need. Thanks!

'''

```
#define MAX_UDP_PKT_IN_MSG 5

CHAR   userData[MAX_UDP_PKT_IN_MSG][10];
WSABUF buf[MAX_UDP_PKT_IN_MSG];
DWORD  pktSent = 0;

/* init socket for UDP */
SOCKET sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);

// calls bind(), connect()
... 

for (int i = 0; i < MAX_UDP_PKT_IN_MSG; i ++) {
    buf[i].len = 10;
    buf[i].buf = &userData[i][0];
}

rc = WSASend(sock, buf, MAX_UDP_PKT_IN_MSG, &pktSent, 0, 0, 0);

...
```

'''

Comment: What you ask for requires 1 buffer per send. `WSASend()` performs only 1 send, thus combining buffers, not N sends for N buffers. Which is kind of implied by this statement in the documentation: "*For **message-oriented** sockets [ie, UDP], do not exceed the maximum message size of the underlying provider, which can be obtained by getting the value of socket option `SO_MAX_MSG_SIZE`. If the data is too long to pass atomically through the underlying protocol the error `WSAEMSGSIZE` is returned, and no data is transmitted.*" Which means all of the submitted buffers are treated as 1 message

Comment: @RemyLebeau you are right! Is there any way to send multiple packets in one call.

Comment: I think you mean messages, not packets. But in any case, no, I'm not aware of any function similar to `sendmmsg()` for Windows sockets.

Answer (score 1):

Use [TransmitPackets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mswsock/nc-mswsock-lpfn_transmitpackets) function.

It is documented to transmit from multiple buffers. There's a flag `TP_ELEMENT_EOP` in `TRANSMIT_PACKETS_ELEMENT` to avoid combining with the next element, presumably, you'll want to use it for every element along with `TP_ELEMENT_MEMORY`.

The documentation on `TRANSMIT_PACKETS_ELEMENT` mentions:

> **TP_ELEMENT_EOP**
>
> Specifies that this element should not be combined with the next element in a single send request from the sockets layer to the transport. This flag is used for granular control of the content of each message on a datagram or message-oriented socket.

So this use case is supported by `TransmitPackets` function.

The use of `TransmitPackets` instead of calling `WSASend` multiple times, each time for each packet is that there's only one OS call, so it is more efficient for performance. Well, it would only matter if everything else is efficient to make OS calls noticeable bottleneck.

Comment: That's exactly what I need. Thanks Alex.